# Speakers can't be detected

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, speakers

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I have a monitor connected using a HDMI cable and a pair of speakers connected using the 3.5 mm jack(at the back of computer) and a USB.

Speakers and monitor are not related with each other. There is no speaker in monitor, it is different device connected with different wire

The speakers were working fine in Windows.
When I started Ubuntu it didnt detect my speaker at all (in Ubuntu sound settings) and used HDMI as speaker which obviously was not intented to happen.

I installed pulse audio and forced it to chose the option of Analog Stereo Output (unplugged) (unavailable).

After that it's working fine but after reboot it resets it.

I dont know why it shows it as unavailable and unplugged and how can I solve this problem permanently?

[This is default when i reboot but its not the speakers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIAOH.png)
[This works when i manually select this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzhq4.png)

Output after `lspci -v`:

````
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 9c89
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 125
    Memory at b1040000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1020000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl```
````

Comment: I don't understand how they are connected to the PC with *both* USB and 3.5mm jack. Is the USB connection only for power delivery? What is the make/model of the speakers?

Comment: @Nmath USB is only for power delivery (Sorry for late reply)

Answer (score 0):

Install Pavucontrol:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Open Pavucontrol, go to the *Output Devices* tab and then set the *Analog Output* as fallback.

[image: gimpimagepavu]

---

You can do it without `pavucontrol` too. Create the file `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-lineout.conf` and add the following in it:

```
[General]
priority = 90
description-key = analog-output-lineout
```

Make sure to adjust the `priority` value to be higher (lower value) than the others. To find the `priority` value of other devices, run:

```
pactl list sinks | grep 'priority'
```